# how to get a value from resource file in the main Activity class when using fragments?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity, android-resources

I'm developing an app with fragments and I want to use a value from "strings.xml" in MainActivity.kt. These are the names of the tabs. But, if I do this:

```
private var title: String = getText(R.string.title).toString()
```

I get this error when I run the code:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
> 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()'
> on a null object reference

If I do:

```
private var title = getText(R.string.title)
```

I also get the error and if I do:

```
private var title = R.string.title
```

I get an integer.
How can I get the atual text I have in `<string name="title">Start</string>`?

Comment: Where are you calling `getText`? Sounds like you might be doing so outside the time when the fragment is actually attached to its activity, resulting in a null context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be careful assigning top-level variables in things like `Activities` and `Fragments` with expressions that require a `Context`. They don't *have* one at construction time, the system provides that later - that's how you end up seeing this kind of error (in your case, it's trying to call `getResources()` on something that should be a `Context`, but it's actually *null*).

A fragment's `Context` has been attached [by the time it enters the CREATED state](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle#fragment_created), so it's safe to access it in `onCreate` or later. So you can make your top-level variable `lateinit` (deferring assignment) and set the value on it later:

```
// define the variable without a value - you need to set a value before this is read!
private lateinit var title: String

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...
    // assign the value when you can
    title = getText(R.string.title).toString()
}
```

Or you could use a `lazy` delegate, which will set the value the first time the variable is accessed, by running a setter function:

```
private val title: String by lazy {
    getText(R.string.title).toString()
}
```

This will fail if the function is called before the `Context` is available too, so in both situations you have to be able to guarantee nothing will try to read from it too early. The `lazy` is arguably neater (no separate assignment) but it does make the value read-only, instead of a `var` - that's probably fine in this situation!

Also if you specifically want a `String` instead of a `CharSequence`, just call `getString` instead of `getText`

Answer (score 0):

You should use getString(), and the function getString (as well as getText) requires your activity to be instantiated.

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        var title = getString(R.string.title)
```